# Testing rollback is caused by @Transaction and not by default test transaction rollback

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-transactions, spring-test

I'm trying to do an Spring Boot integration test where I call a method of a service which is composed by other two methods methods (all are `@Transactional`). One of them save a record in ddbb and the other throws a RuntimeException (where, in running production app cause a Rollback of the saved record.

I want to test this rollback behaviour in the test (for example that if the methods don't have `@Transactional` the rollback is not done). Currently if the `@Rollback(true)` the rollback is done even if the methods don't have the `@Transactional` and if the `@Rollback(false)` any rollback is done. The objective is to test that the rollback is done caused by the transaction reaction to the runtime exception and not because the test automatically rollback.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration
class RefundServiceIT {

    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    void testTransactions() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> {
            refundService.refund();
        });
        //assertions rollback caused by runtime is done
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class refundService {

    @Transactional
    public refund() {
       saveddbb();
       wrong();
    }

    @Transactional
    public saveddbb() {
        //save an element in ddbb
    }

    @Transactional
       public wrong() {
       //throw new RuntimeException()
    }

}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to add add transaction manager [see docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html)

Comment: thanks borino, I've added and positively, if I debug : TestTransaction.isActive() is false but with it, the commit is not done. I add the changes as an edit in the question.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? 
I have an almost identical problem.
My service method is rolling back as expected, when running in production, or just when called from a Rest endpoint, but in my test it never rolls back, even when I test with inputs similar to what was used above.